# OpenAI API error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.error'"

Tags: python, flask, openai-api

I am having an issue installing the `openai.error` package in Python. This is what I am trying to install:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import openai
from openai.error import OpenAIError
import re
import os
```

After installing the OpenAI package, I thought the `openai.error` package would install automatically. However, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Downloads\Examiner.Production\IELTS_Examiner_Private\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from openai.error import OpenAIError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.error'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported the `OpenAIError` class from the `openai` incorrectly.

Change this...

```
from openai.error import OpenAIError
```

...to this.

```
from openai import OpenAIError
```

Comment: i use openai.error 
because it is easier to write like this:     except OpenAIError as e:
        content = "The server is experiencing a high volume of requests. Please try again later." instead using all types of errors

Comment: The problem was actually elsewhere. See my edited answer.